# pool.apply_async takes so long to finish, how to speed up?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I call pool.apply_async() with 14 cores.

```
   import multiprocessing 
   from time import time
   import timeit

   informative_patients = informative_patients_2500_end[20:]
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool(14)
   results = []
   wLength = [20,30,50]

   start = time()

   for fn in informative_patients:
        result = pool.apply_async(compute_features_test_set, args = (fn, 
        wLength), callback=results.append)

   pool.close()

   pool.join()


   stop = timeit.default_timer()

   print stop - start
```

The problem is it finishes calling compute_features_test_set() function for the first 13 data in less than one hour, but it takes more than one hour to finish the last one. The size of the data for all the 14 data-set is the same. I tried putting pool.terminate() after pool.close() but in this case it doesn't even start the pool and terminate the pool immediately without going inside the for loop. This always happen in the same way and if I use more cores and more data set, always the last one takes so long to finish. My compute_features_test_set() function is a simple feature extraction code and works correctly. I work on a server with Linux red hat 6, python 2.7 and jupyter. Computation time is important to me and my question is what is wrong here and how I can fix it to get the all the computation done in a reasonable time?

Comment: How many **real core's** did you have? How big is the size of `informative_parients`?

Comment: I think I have 32 real core on the server that I work on. informative_parients has only 14 patient id that I call my feature extraction function inside the for loop on any of the patient id. So, informative_parients is an array of 14 strings, each with length 8. I collect the information for each patient as the input of my feature extraction function using a patient id.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ...  what is wrong here and how I can fix it

Couldn't catch this as a `multiprocessing` issue.
But **How** do you get this: *"always the last one takes so long to finish"*?
You are using `callback=results.append` instead of a own `function`?
Edit your Question and show **How** you `timeit` **one** Process Time.
Also add your Python Version to your Question.

**Do the following to verify it's not a Data issue**:

```
   start = time()
   results.append(
       compute_features_test_set(<First informative_patients>, wLength
       )
   stop = timeit.default_timer()
   print stop - start 

   start = time()
   results.append(
       compute_features_test_set(<Last informative_patients>, wLength
       )
   stop = timeit.default_timer()
   print stop - start
```

**Compare the two times you get.**